# Decimal in .NET

Tags: c#

I have a decimal in .NET and I need to store it to a column in a typed dataset that is a string. I need the decimal to be stored to two decimal places. Even though I use `Math.Round(value,2)` and I do a `ToString()`, it doesnt work.

Any ideas and suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I mean for example if I have 0 as the value, it gives 0.0 as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do `decimalVar.ToString ("#.##");`

or

```
decimal value = 1.2345;
string rounded = value.ToString("d2");
```

See [.NET Format String Cheat Sheets](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/index.php/net-cheat-sheets)

Comment: `d2` will not keep the decimal places.

Comment: Actually use ToString("0.00")

Comment: decimalVar.ToString ("#.##") seemed to work. But does it also round or does it only get the first two digits. I mean lets say we have 1.2345, does it return 1.20 or 1.23.

Comment: Thanks, that worked ! that was the simplest solution I needed. Thanks everybody else for pouring in your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`[decimal].ToString("F")`  or
`[decimal].ToString("F2")`

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal myDecimal = 123.456;
string myString = myDecimal.toString("N2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your value as `0.0000M` instead `0`. Example below

```
decimal a = 1.6644M;  

Math.Round(a, 2);
```

returns 1.66

Answer (score 0):

To avoid as much as it possible "strange" floating point calculation problem I would suggest:

First: define your presicion: in your case it seems to be 2 numbers after point. 
Second: convert `decimal` to `integer`

```
int iValue = (int)(Math.Round(decimalValue) * 100); // 10 ^ 2 of precision
```

Third: store in `DataSet` that string and not floated point value string. (why not integer at this point?)

If you need to show to user the value stored in `DataSet`, make an inverse operation.

**EDIT:**

Having in this way a solid data on you datamodel which is `DataSet` you can manage your presentation layer `DataView`/`DataBinging`... in a way you like in order to support any culture of your client and decrease probbability to have "floating point ariphmetics mess".

Regards.